# Why are there limits on domain name lengths?

Tags: hash, dns

From what I know, domains seem to be keys into a hash of the DNS where the value is the resource records for the domain name. Why are they limited in length? The specifications I found say that a domain name:

+Has a maximum label length of 63 characters

+Has a maximum of 127 labels.

+Cannot be no more than 255 bytes of data

And theres also all sorts of restrictions upon special character ordering, etc. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**label length**
The 63-byte limit is because in the DNS protocol, labels stored as , length is a single byte, but two high bits of the length field reserved for something else (compression) thus leaving 6 bits for the length itself, 2^6=64 possible values - 0..63.

> To simplify implementations, the total length of a domain name (i.e.,
>   label octets and label length octets) is restricted to 255 octets or
>   less.

I did not find a limit for 127 labels in the specifications. It arises simply from the fact that the whole domain name is up to 255 bytes and label is always no less than 2 bytes (single letter and the dot or length and the letter).